# Django Rest Framework 3.2.3 pagination not working for generics.ListCreateAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The docs say I should get pagination for free when subclassing a generic List or ListCreateAPIView but there is no sign of any pagination happening.

Here is what I have in settings...

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':   
        'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 25,
    'MAX_PAGE_SIZE': 50,
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',
    'TEST_REQUEST_RENDERER_CLASSES': (...
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (...
    )
}
```

My View:

```
class RequestList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    # set context for serializers
    def get_serializer_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'request': self.request,
            'view': self,
            'format': self.format_kwarg,
            'request_type_id': 1}
    return context 

    request_type_code_model_map = {
        "S": Request.objects.filter(request_type_id=1, status='open'),
        ...}

    def get(self, request, request_type_code="S", format=None, *args,  **kwargs):

        queryset = self.request_type_code_model_map.get(
            request_type_code, "S")
        serializer_class = RequestSerializer
        serializer = serializer_class(
            instance=queryset, context=self.get_serializer_context(),
            many=True)

     return Response(serializer.data)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I've tried creating a custom paginator class, setting various configuration options in settings, but nothing I do seems to make any attempt at paginating. Pagination is working for Users and Groups which are using ViewSets, but not any of my views using generics. Any ideas, a clue as to what I am missing, or a solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You get the pagination for free provided you don't override parts that call it.
You can browse the [list source](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L39) to see how it's implemented and how you should write your `get` method.

Comment: Thanks very much Linovia. This did the trick. I had assumed this was probably the case yesterday and implemented something that worked but didn't get me the visible controls in the browseable API. This was the key. Much appreciated!